# Receiving a lot of errors from /dev/sda

Tags: hardware, disk

I have an Asus EeeBox PC - B204( original specs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_EeeBox_PC ) running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS; 
The only thing changed was the original hdd to a Kingston V300 SSD;

So far so good. But lately I started receiving some errors, after some time the system was entering in a readonly mode - not even connecting through ssh was possible;

So I removed the ssd, connected it to another computer and ran some detect/repair tests using Hirens Boot CD;
Then, from windows using Kingston SSD Manager I updated the ssd firmware;

I mounted the ssd back on my linux machine, in 2 days no freezing / switching to read-only mode but I get a lot of these(every 1-2 minute):

```
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:e0:d0:cc/00:00:00:00:00/ec tag 0 dma 4096 in
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017]          res 40/00:01:a0:20:cf/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1: soft resetting link
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[Wed Mar  1 20:41:03 2017] ata1: EH complete
```

Any ideas how to identify the problem? It's my ssd broken? Or my sata controller?

`smartctl -a /dev/sda` returns

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-4.4.0-64-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

START OF INFORMATION SECTION
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SV300S37A120G
Serial Number:    50026B785201EA6B
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 85201ea6b
Firmware Version: 60AABBF0
User Capacity:    120,033,041,920 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Mar  1 21:35:08 2017 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
 START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x05) Offline data collection activity
                                        was aborted by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  33) The self-test routine was interrupted
                                        by the host with a hard or soft reset.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Abort Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   095   095   050    Old_age   Always       -       2/22219071
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       4408h+22m+17.710s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       659
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       69
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   041   048   000    Old_age   Offline      -       41 (Min/Max 19/48)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   041   048   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 19/48)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   105   105   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/22219071
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   105   105   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/22219071
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   105   105   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2/22219071
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       2924
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       2142
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       2142
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4201

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      10%      4327         -
# 2  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      4314         -
# 3  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      10%      4312         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        10         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thank you.

Comment: "Frozen" indicates it's a SATA problem; I have similar messages with a cheap Chinese SATA-IDE bridge for my IDE CD-ROM. Might be SATA controller (or the firmware in the controller) on each end, cabling, timing (also in the driver), ... difficult to pinpoint. At least cabling is easy to check.